# Getting user information from Facebook using graph API

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbconnect, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to get basic user information from Facebook, but having some problem in the following code

```
-(void)checkForAccessToken:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSError *error;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"access_token=(.*)&" options:0 error:&error];
    if (regex != nil) {
        **NSTextCheckingResult *firstMatch = [regex firstMatchInString:urlString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [urlString length])];
        if (firstMatch) {
            NSRange accessTokenRange = [firstMatch rangeAtIndex:1];
            NSString *accessToken = [urlString substringWithRange:accessTokenRange];
            accessToken = [accessToken stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [_delegate accessTokenFound:accessToken];               
        }**
    }
}
```

In the firstMatch I am getting NULL that's why  [_delegate accessTokenFound:accessToken];  this methods not get called.

Can anyone please help me out so that I would be able to user information from Facebook

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the facebook sdk? Why would you want to get the access token that way instead of using the official Graph API?

Comment: You would usually only need to do as suggested in the Facebook dev manuals: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the fbdid login method after initialising it with app id and credentials.-

```
(void)fbDidLogin {

NSLog(@"fbDidLogin");
isFacebookLoaded=YES;


NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"i am in and my acees token is %@ %@ and call me.CALLshowAloadingView",[facebook accessToken],[facebook expirationDate]) ;
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
if ( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showAloadingView)] ) 
{
    NSLog(@" CALLshowAloadingView");
    // calling delegate method. For this method to function, the delegate should be implemented in the calling class.
    [delegate showAloadingView];                
}


// Inform the delegate that Login is successful
if ( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(loginStatus:)] ) {
    // calling delegate method. For this method to function, the delegate should be implemented in the calling class.
    [delegate loginStatus:YES];                 
    return;
}
```

}